# Probability with random intersecting lines

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Suppose we have $n$ random lines that intersect the coordinates $[0,1]^2$. To choose a line randomly, we must first randomly choose a point on a side, choose any point on either of the other three sides and connect the points with a line.

The question then is: what is the probability that one of the regions formed by these intersecting lines has area greater than $1/2$?  Obviously the probability for $n=1$ is $1$.  Does anyone see the answer for higher values?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Do you mean "...what is the probability that one of the regions formed by these intersection lines has area greater than $1/2$?"

Comment: Are the starting coordinates chosen from the set $[0,1]^2$?

Comment: To Sean Roberson, yes sorry for that error.

Comment: To David K, the lines have random slopes and the coordinates from which they begin (or from which they first intersect (0,1)) are random as well. So, yes I think.

Comment: Do you knpw that the definition of a random line is usually not the one you give. Usually, it is a line with equation $x\cos \theta + y \sin \theta -p=0$ where $\theta$ is uniform in $[0, 2 \pi]$ and p is uniform in $[0,d]$ ?

Comment: When you say "starting coordinates" I assume you are strictly speaking about points on the boundary. Is this a correct interpretation?

Comment: How are you choosing a slope “randomly,” which in problem shorthand generally means that the values are uniformly distributed? The slope of a line can be any real value (and infinite for vertical lines).

Comment: Do phrases “randomly choose a point” and “choose any point” mean that random point is distributed uniformly?

Comment: How are regions formed? When you say $p=1$ for $n=1$ that seems to suggest you can use the sides of the square as well as the random lines?

Comment: This is a duplication of a [post in MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275655)